# Delete multiline blocks with sed non-greedy

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, replace, delete

How can one remove code blocks starting with `/** START */` and ending with `/** END */` using `sed` non-greedily considering that code blocks are multiline and empty lines may occur within START-END blocks?

#### START marker single line comment

[SOLUTION](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/718343/delete-multiline-blocks-with-sed-non-greedy#comment1361934_718343)

INPUT:

```javascript
class MyClass {
    keepField;
    /** START */
    deleteField;
    /** END */

    construct() {
        /** START */
        this.deleteField = 'delete';
        /** END */
        this.keepField = 'keep';
        /** START */
        this.deleteFunc();
        /** END */
    }
    
    /** START */
    deleteFunc() {
        this.keepField = 'delete';

        if (true) {
            console.debug('Line before if statement is empty.');
        }
    } /** END */
}
```

OUTPUT:

```javascript
class MyClass {
    keepField;

    construct() {
        this.keepField = 'keep';
    }
    
}
```

I have tried the following `sed '/./{H;$!d} ; x ; s/START.*END//' MyClass.js` as described in the [sed manual > Multiline techniques section](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Multiline-techniques).

However, the above command is greedy in blocks when there are no empty lines and multiple START-END blocks (like in the `constructor`) and also empty lines of code are not taken into account inside START-END blocks (like in the `deleteFunc` function).

Any idea how the above can be solved with `sed` or any other command line tool such as `awk`?

#### START marker is block comment

[SOLUTION](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/718527/542452)

INPUT:

```javascript
class MyClass {
    /**
     * same code as above only this time the START block is 
     * multiline like below.
     */

    /**
     * START
     */
    deleteFunc() {
        this.keepField = 'delete';

        if (true) {
            console.debug('Line before if statement is empty.');
        }
    } /** END */
}
```

OUTPUT should also be:

```javascript
class MyClass {
    keepField;

    construct() {
        this.keepField = 'keep';
    }

}
```

Comment: `sed '/START/,/END/d' file`

Comment: That does the work, thanks! There is only one edge case. I've edited the post and added it.

Comment: `sed '/\* START/,/END/d'`

Comment: sed and awk are very general text manipulation tools, so parsing code isn't recommended because of its complexity: you can have comments in the middle or end of a line instead of at the start, you can have those keywords in a string, many edge cases. Or even have START by accident in the middle of another comment like on your second example.

Comment: @HatLess unfortunately `sed '/\* START/,/END/d'` doesn't seem to work for the edge-case.

Comment: @seshoumara we realised that. in our case, we can minimise the edge cases to some degree. with the first suggestion by @HatLess, we are already one step further. if we could also solve the edge-case using `sed` that would be great! in any case, what would be your suggestion to solve the above presented?

Comment: Why isn't the last END comment on a new line like all the other special comments? It is at the end of an actual code line, which again is another edge case. Would make life simpler if you ensure comments are always on separate lines. In fact if so I have a sed solution.

Comment: When providing sample input/output, don't describe what it contains, e.g. "same code as above", simply **show** what it contains, e.g. copy the code from above into the 2nd example. Otherwise you're not giving us something we can simply copy/paste to test with and instead asking all of us to do the work of editing the example you provide to create something we can test with to try to help you.

Comment: @seshoumara If `/** END */` present on a line, this line should be removed.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the tip! I updated the example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is an excellent tool for doing simple s/old/new/ operations. For anything else, just use awk for clarity, efficiency, robustness, portability, maintainability, etc. For example, using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ rec = rec $0 ORS }
END {
    while ( match(rec,/\/\*\*[[:space:]*]*END[[:space:]*]*\*\//) ) {
        toEnd = substr(rec,1,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)
        sub(/(\n[[:blank:]]*)?\/\*\*[[:space:]*]*START[[:space:]*]*\*\/.*/,"",toEnd)
        printf "%s", toEnd
        rec = substr(rec,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    printf "%s", rec
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
class MyClass {
    keepField;

    construct() {
        this.keepField = 'keep';
    }

}

class MyClass {
    /**
     * same code as above only this time the START block is
     * multiline like below.
     */

}
```

If you don't have a POSIX awk then change every `[:space:]` to  `\t\n` and `[:blank:]` to  `\t` (first char of each string is a literal blank char) and then it'll work in any awk.

The above was run on this input file:

```
$ cat file
class MyClass {
    keepField;
    /** START */
    deleteField;
    /** END */

    construct() {
        /** START */
        this.deleteField = 'delete';
        /** END */
        this.keepField = 'keep';
        /** START */
        this.deleteFunc();
        /** END */
    }

    /** START */
    deleteFunc() {
        this.keepField = 'delete';

        if (true) {
            console.debug('Line before if statement is empty.');
        }
    } /** END */
}

class MyClass {
    /**
     * same code as above only this time the START block is
     * multiline like below.
     */

    /**
     * START
     */
    deleteFunc() {
        this.keepField = 'delete';

        if (true) {
            console.debug('Line before if statement is empty.');
        }
    } /** END */
}
```

but consider also this pathological case where the whole input is on a single line:

```
$ cat file
class MyClass { keepField; /** START */ deleteField; /** END */ construct() { /** START */ this.deleteField = 'delete'; /** END */ this.keepField = 'keep'; /** START */ this.deleteFunc(); /** END */ } /** START */ deleteFunc() { this.keepField = 'delete'; if (true) { console.debug('Line before if statement is empty.'); } } /** END */ }
```

and note that the above script handles it correctly (as it also would many other unstated cases I could imagine except where your start/end strings could be inside literal strings or themselves inside comments - you can't handle such cases with pattern matching as we're doing):

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
class MyClass { keepField;  construct() {  this.keepField = 'keep';  }  }
```

Comment: This works well! We now realised though that there are also other edge cases when the START marker is a block comment. So we might go with the single line markers. In which case @HatLess's solution in the first comment would work well.

Comment: I don't know what that means, sorry. Post a new question if you have different input than shown in this question that you need to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez 's~ +/?\*+ START( \*)?([^*]*\*+)([^\n]*\n[^*]*\*+)? END[^\n]*\n~~g' input_file
```

```
class MyClass {
    keepField;

    construct() {
        this.keepField = 'keep';
    }
    
}
```

```
class MyClass {
    /**
     * same code as above only this time the START block is 
     * multiline like below.
     */

    /**
}
```

Comment: `/**` should also be deleted. unfortunately our `sed` build does not support the `-z` option.

Comment: @0x1505 Are you on a mac? If so, you can install GNU sed with brew

Comment: If possible we want to cover more systems with one command. It could be unpleasant for mac devs to require them to have brew installed. Nevertheless, I linked to your first comment on the post, which solves the problem when the START marker is a single line comment.